# Implementing the A(:,k)=b; Matlab-like syntax in a C++ matrix library

Tags: c++, template-meta-programming, expression-templates

I have developed an expression templates-based C++ matrix class of my own. I have overloaded the `()` operator so that I can read or write element matrices as, for example,

```
cout << A(i,j) << endl;
```

and

```
A(i,j)=b;
```

respectively.
I have also implemented a `Range` class to enable Matlab-like reads as

```
cout << A(Range(3,5),Range(0,10)) << endl;
```

The template `Matrix` class is exemplified as

```
template <typename OutType>
class Matrix
{
    private:
        int Rows_;          //number of Rows
        int Columns_;       //number of Columns
        OutType *data_;     //row-major order allocation
    public:

        // --- Access operators 
        inline OutType & operator()(const int i, const int j)       { return data_[IDX2R(i,j,GetColumns())]; }
        inline OutType   operator()(const int i, const int j) const { return data_[IDX2R(i,j,GetColumns())]; }

        // --- SubExpressions - Range Range
        inline Expr<SubMatrixExpr<const OutType*,OutType>,OutType> operator()(Range range1, Range range2)
        {   typedef SubMatrixExpr<const OutType*,OutType> SExpr; 
                return Expr<SExpr,OutType>(SExpr(data_,Rows_,Columns_,range1.numelements_,range2.numelements_,range1.start_,range1.step_,range2.start_,range2.step_),
                        range1.numelements_,range2.numelements_); 
        }
}
```

I would now like to enable Matlab-like assignments as

```
A(Range(3,5),Range(0,10))=B;
```

where `B` is an appropriate matrix.

I think that, to achieve the Matlab-like syntax above, two possibilities would be

1. overloading the `()` operator, so that it returns an array of pointers, and then overloading the `=` operator so that the latter could act between an array of pointers and a `Matrix`;
2. exploit the already performed overload of the `()` operator indicated above and overloading the `=` operator so that the latter could act between an expression and a `Matrix`.

Maybe the first option is not very convenient, especilly for very large matrices.
Am I correct? Are there other more efficient/effective possibilities using perhaps more sophisticated C++ features (e.g., move semantics)?

Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I think your best bet is to have a non-const version of `operator()(Range, Range)` return a proxy object that has an overloaded assignment operator that knows how to assign to a range (back into the original matrix for example).